# entering multiple values in link list in java

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

Using LinkedList I want to access the data members of the class StudData. `StudData` should have an array of object. This code doesn't show errors but doesn't execute successfully either.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudData {

    public int roll_no;
    public String name;
    private Scanner sc;

    void enter() {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter:");
        sc.nextInt(roll_no);
        sc.next(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudData p= new StudData();
        LinkedList <StudData> ll=new LinkedList<StudData>();

        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            p.enter();
            ll.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"This code doesn't shows errors, but doesn't compiles either."* -- This makes no sense. If it doesn't compile, the compiler will give you an error stating why.  Otherwise, how do you know it doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1):

The code shared should compile ideally. But there would be a possible exception at:

```
sc.nextInt(roll_no); // roll_no is 0 by default
```

Hence this would throw an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: radix:0`. In case you want to take roll_no as an input from user, you can change the code to:

```
roll_no = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you made a mistake (although I am on the train working with my phone)

```
    sc.nextInt(roll_no);
    sc.next(name);
```

Should be:

```
    roll_no = sc.nextInt();
    name = sc.next();
```

The variables can't be set by passing them as arguments, because a String is immutable and an int is a primitive.